# How to put two planes on top of each other in ParaView, and with different coloring?

Tags: 2d, visualization, paraview

Ok, so I have several ParaView-problems that all seem to come together. I'll explain all, please stick with me and don't be afraid to ask for more details:

First off, I have two 2D data-files that I output (STRUCTURED_POINTS). The first one of them is simply one that describes the geometry of the structure, named Geometry2D.vtk. The second one are multiple files that form a movie of an electrical signal running over this geometry, stored into ParaviewMovie****.vtk, where the **** are ranging from 0000 to 9999, where each step is a second that has passed.

Now is the thing that I would like the voltage to run, while I can see the structure of the surface. Therefore I would like to get a view as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYmmo.gif). (I would like to put the picture here, but I apparently need 10 reputation to do so) This way I can put the voltage on the top panel and the geometry on the lower one. I have however no clue how to accomplish this feature.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYmmo.gif]

The next problem is then that both these data-sets have different scales, the geometry one are discrete numbers from 0 to 10 and the voltage file ranges from -100 to 50 continuously. It is for me however only possible to set one scale/coloring for all datasets at once. How do I put multiple scales/coloring, so for each dataset another scale/coloring?

If you are able to explain this, keep in mind that I am fairly new to ParaView and am only able to do things visually, not with the use of the programming environment that I know is also a possibility.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understood your question, so I would comment but I don't have the necessary reputation to it... 
You can email me with a more detailed question so I could understand you and try to help in a better way.

But you sure can use different coloring in different datasets. If your datasets are both colored by an scalar value, they have to have different names so you can color then with different color presets.

About the different scales, you have to use the "Transform" filter and do some math to put the geometries in the same scale.